# What is responsible for pausing code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There's something that's pausing my code in Unity and I'm not sure what it is. I've searched for `Debug.Break()` statements everywhere and don't have any. What's causing this issue?

(Asked on behalf of [Jabrils](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQALLeQPoZdZC4JNUboVEUg) who could have been saved by this question.)

Comment: Check that you dont have PauseOnError activated in the error console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any `Debug.Break()` statements, and your code doesn't have any other breakpoints to look at, check the ["Pause on Error" functionality of Unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/29176/when-i-press-play-it-just-pauses-right-after.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20getting%20an,here%20labelled%20%27Error%20Pause%27.). It can be turned off by clicking a UI button when you have the console open.